# Infinite precision

Tags: logical-deduction, science

The man tells you, "To enter the door of infinite precision, you must complete all of these tasks **perfectly**:

- Hold in front of me a baby that is exactly two days old.
- Bring me a metal object that weighs exactly one kilogram.*
- Bring me a stone object that weighs exactly one pound.*
- Bring me a glass containing something other than water that is exactly the same density as water.
- Write all the digits of pi."

"I'm sorry", you say, "but that is impossible.  I can complete four, but there is one I cannot do."

Which task can't you accomplish, and why?

(The explanation should state how you *can* do the other four tasks, as well).

Hint:

> Keep in mind that this puzzle was spoken, not written down.  This may help with one of the tasks.

*If you want to get technical (and I know some of you do), consider these objects with a *mass* of one kilogram and one pound.

Comment: Love when the answer seems so obvious you're scared to answer! Ha!

Comment: Have you actually been given "this piece of paper" ?

Comment: Do you have a pen that will write on "this piece of paper"?

Comment: Is the man standing normally?  Facing you?

Comment: @BrentHackers nothing funny going on with the piece of paper, and I deleted the mention of the paper just to avoid confusion.  I can't imagine what you are getting at with the other comment...haha!  The position he is standing won't prevent you from completing any of the tasks.

Comment: So...what's the precise moment of birth, crowning? Placental afterbirth?  First breath? Cutting the umbilical cord?  An arbitrary timestamp taken by a bystander?  What if its a c-section?   If it's not on the birth certificate, is it not "certified"?

Comment: @user662852 the solution to that one doesn't require knowing that information.

Comment: I'm very confused. Has anyone gotten the actual answer yet?

Comment: I hope you are a physicist, dan1111!

Comment: @TonyEnnis I'm not a physicist but I'd welcome a physicist's explanation of why I'm wrong :)  Anyway, I thought this was a fun idea.

Comment: It's certainly interesting, but it becomes a science experiment, not a riddle.

Comment: Could you bring scale made of stone and weigh a one-pound note with it?

Comment: Unless the stone problem is intended to be solvable, you'll want to further specify *rest* mass. Mass is dependent on the relative velocity of the stone to the man judging its mass.

Comment: This question has been reworded five times so far (currently at revision 6). I guess OP is not ready to enter the door of infinite precision any time soon (more precisely, in fintie time).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen haha, true enough!

Answer (score 23):

The task you can't accomplish is:

> Bring an object with a weight of exactly one pound.  Nothing is *exactly* one pound with infinite precision.  [There are several definitions of the pound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(mass)), but the most common one is defined as "0.45359237 kilograms".  No matter how hard you try, you aren't going to make something with that exact weight, it will weigh slightly more or slightly less.  There are several other definitions of the pound, but they all have the same problem.  At least one of them is defined by an "official object" but it is not made of stone. **As some people have pointed out, there are solutions for "weight" in the precise sense of that word.  I was really thinking of mass but was imprecise (as this distinction is not present in common language).  If you want to take it as "weight" then fair enough, in that case all tasks are possible.**

How you *can* accomplish the other tasks:

> If you hold a baby that is slightly less than two days old, until it is slightly more than two days old, it will pass through the exact moment of being two days old.

...

> A kilogram is defined as ["equal to the mass of the International Prototype of the Kilogram"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram) (which is metal).  So you can bring this object, which is exactly one kilogram by definition. (This would be difficult, as you would have to steal it or convince someone to let you borrow it...but it's not logically impossible).

...

> You couldn't make anything of an exact specified density. However, since the temperature and pressure of the water are not specified, you only have to get within the range of potential densities of water, which is an easy task.

...

> I had in mind that you write the phrase "all the digits of pi" on a piece of paper.  Given that this is a spoken puzzle, it surely fulfills one interpretation of what the man said. However, I suppose you could write 0123456789, as an alternative suggested by Brent Hackers.

Comment: So a pound just isn't an exact enough measurement?  I'd still have been guessing in a million years haha.

Comment: @BrentHackers added slightly more explanation to clarify.

Comment: I guess science isn't my thing... :/

Comment: Why is it not possible to weigh something to 0.45359237000 (recurring) kilograms? If you only need to be in that range, bring a stone that is slightly heavier, keep chipping at it, and at some point it has to be equivalent to a pound.

Comment: @Inazuma "at some point it has to be equivalent to a pound." Not to infinite precision.  Even if you chip off one atom at a time it will never be *exactly* that mass.

Comment: I don't believe this answer is accurate. A pound may have several definitions, but at one point in space, there is _a_ pound. I would bring the questioner a pound+ of something, and let the extra evaporate slowly. Like the baby passing through the two year mark, the item will eventually weigh a pound per the kilogram definition. How long will it weigh the correct amount? Probably longer than the baby was exactly 2 years old...

Comment: @TonyEnnis, the problem with this idea is that, unlike time, the stone is made up of discrete units.  Any decay is going to involve losing individual atoms or molecules, so it will not pass through every possible mass as it decays.  Of course it will be a very, very close approximation of a pound at some point, but it will never be exactly a pound.

Comment: @dan1111 have you checked whether 1/0.4559237 is rational? If it is then there might be a chance that to build a stone weighing that much.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu it is rational.  But the odds that a particular set of molecules add up to *exactly* 0.45359237 of the set of molecules in the official Kilogram seem very small.  And even if there were such a possibility, there is no way you could measure the official kilogram or construct the stone with sufficient precision.

Comment: Just move the stone up and down, and its weight will change with the gravity changes.

Comment: Take an object just under a pound and accelerate it until it passes 1 pound.

Comment: It was my mistake to say weight when I meant mass...

Comment: Grab an object that weighs almost one pound and accelerate it to relativistic speeds in front of him.

Comment: Isn't he international  pound defined as exactly 0.45359237 kg??

Comment: @dan1111  "the odds are very small" is far from a proof. "Stone" is very undefined, so you can toy with a lot of different elements and their isotopes. Considering that 1kg 'metal' is composed of an integer vale of neutrons, protons and electrons, I'm rather positive you can get to the same integer values building a stone when using trace elements to balance out the numbers. Now HOW one would practically build a 'stone' at atomic precision is another question, but hard != impossible.

Comment: @roland: I was thinking about that on my way from home, even was planning to put it as answer. And for others 1/0.45359237 is not rational according to online rational calculator. But if it is weight just move away from the earth and if it is mass, accelerate (relativistic effects are measurable even with regularly moving objects, you don't need to get to a sizable fraction of lightspeed).

Comment: @BmyGuest, the mass of an object is not uniquely determined by any integer number of neutrons, protons, and electrons that are in it. How they are bound changes the mass. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_number#Mass_number_and_isotopic_mass.

Comment: This has gotten very technical.  Far beyond the intent of the puzzle?  Interesting as the discussion is, I can't help but think that the spirit of the puzzle is a little broken.  Also, I think the knowledge and science tags probably apply just as much as the logic-puzzle one?

Comment: @TonyEnnis, troy pound, (373.24 g) or avoirdupois pound? (453.59 g)

Comment: @SeanC The OP did not specify, so any will do.

Comment: @dan1111 If you want to get really technical, special relativity should do it just fine.  In fact, I do think it is possible to hit exactly one pound with relativistic effects.  Not to mention, the 'discrete' nature of weight is the same for time.  It might be impossible to get the baby to be 2 days old, counting in Planck units...

Comment: @SimpleArt You could spin that further: "*hold* the baby" implies a static location in both time and space at the same time. (Zero velocity, zero delta in space.) Uncertainty principle doesn't like this neither...

Comment: @BmyGuest, creating an object with an exact mass of one pound is certainly not just hard but impossible. Even if there exists some combination of particles that adds up to the right mass, there is no conceivable way to make such a stone.  Note that all the other tasks are straightforwardly possible without any special tools or technology needed.

Comment: @SimpleArt the stone is actually made up of units.  Time is not--units are just used to measure it.

Comment: @dan1111 Uh, there is indeed a planck time unit.  Time is discrete just as well.

Comment: The ISO definition of a kilogram no longer depends on an actual mass. THe reference mass being built (of single-crystal silicon, as it happens) is being cut to match the quantum-based definition.

Comment: @SimpleArt I understand that unit exists and is used to measure time.  But that doesn't mean that time itself is discrete!  This is a fundamental distinction.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft this has not happened yet as far as I can tell: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_redefinition_of_SI_base_units

Comment: Rather than nitpick your answer, I'm going to nitpick the *existence* of your answer.  While it is acceptable for a poster to answer their own question, it is not at all customary for that answer to be added not even an hour after posting.  Give people a chance to answer!  Rather, you should refine your question and lead people in the right direction before spoiling the fun for everyone else.

Comment: Why can't you weigh a British pound and get a stone that weighs the same amount?

Answer (score 13):

My understanding is that

> The [one] stone object can't weigh one pound because one stone weighs 14 pounds!

•Write all the digits of pi on this piece of paper

> The digits that make up Pi is infinite (impossible then?)  NO!  you can just write "0123456789"?

•Hold in front of me a baby that is exactly two days old.

> A baby can surely be exactly 2 days old if only for a moment.

•Bring me a metal object that weighs exactly one kilogram.*

> A 1kg metal weight?

•Bring me a glass filled with something other than water that is exactly the same density as water.

> Struggled with this one because as BmyGuest (+1) said water doesn't have a specific density.  It changes based on it's contents.  Salt water is water and yet more dense than fresh water, so maybe pick a liquid with a density somewhere in that range?  a mixture of d<1 and d>1 liquids should do the trick according to klm123.  Thanks (+1).

Comment: Your last observation/conclusion is clever, but as there is a ":" after perfectly and a bullet-list, I would be very disappointed if the overal task would be considered "a task" of the puzzle.

Comment: Good point.  My first answer seemed the only one I couldn't fault but that also seemed far too obvious to be correct...  WAIT!  I get how that can be done.  I will update!

Comment: Technically, nothing weighs a kilogram, since that is a unit of mass. Not sure if that's what the OP is going for, though, but they did make a point of using pound and kilogram.

Comment: "metal object that weighs exactly one kilogram"  can be the weight itself?(one which is used in weighing scale?)

Comment: Got it!?  I got it right? :)

Comment: @MikeM. that isn't what I was going for, and I added a note to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: Water density is not constant. (Depends on pressure & temperature)

Comment: @BrentHackers, I like your second point--not what I was thinking of, but I think it works!

Comment: @dan1111 So what was your method for writing down all of the digits in Pi?  Wouldn't you end up with a very achy wrist?  OH!  "PIE"?  I'd say they were characters rather than digits...

Comment: I'm totally *not* getting your first arguement about the stone object, Brent.

Comment: @BmyGuest Edited for clarification

Comment: What is the problem with water? just make a mixture of d < 1 and d > 1 liquids. You can make it go from ~0.9 density to ~1.1 density just in front of the man, exactly like the child age.

Comment: Can anyone explain me (not-native English speaker) in details, why you can't do the thing in the first spoiler? Can't find anything like this in thesaurus.

Comment: I have posted my answer so you can see what I was thinking.

Comment: @klm123 in Britain a "stone" is a unit of mass weighing 14 pounds, so the idea is that you couldn't have a stone weighing one pound.  However, I don't think this really works.  "A stone object" isn't naturally read as an object weighing one stone, and anyway, nothing the man said requires you to interpret it this way.

Comment: @dan1111, thanks. May be the problem with stone is that you Simply can't find any stone, which would wight exactly 1kg (with infinite precision)? I like this answer more, since you reinterpret the pi-task as you like, so who forces you to reinterpret stone-task in a way you can't complete it by definition? (oh, I see, the OP already gave the answer).

Comment: Like the Pi thing, which you can interpret literally, why not do the same thing for #4? "Bring me a glass containing something other than water that is exactly the same density as water." could mean putting a piece of paper or something that has "something other than water that is exactly the same density as water." on it.

Answer (score 12):

Is it:

> Glass

because:

> baby - hold around the exact time
>  metal - scales weigh things and can be made from metal and can weigh exactly $1kg$
>  stone - perfectly possible
>  $\pi$ - base dependent so $0,1$

and so:

> the speaker said 'Bring me a glass, containing something other than water, that is exactly the same density as water.' Note the commas, and glass cannot have the same density as water.

Comment: Ha.  Clever.  I like this answer better than the correct solution! +1

Comment: I would say the weakness here is that you  allow creative interpretation of some sentences to solve them (stone, metal, pi) and yet force a particular interpretation of the other challenge to say it's not possible.  But overall +1 for some interesting creative ideas.

Comment: You answer does create the possibility that all might be achievable.

Comment: I wouldn't consider a punctuation trick to be in the spirit of the puzzle.

Comment: Normal plate glass has a higher density, but aerogel is also glass with much lower density, so a suitable composite would have neutral density.

Answer (score 5):

I am not quite satisfied with any of the explanations, so, here's my own interpretation...

> You cannot hold in front of them a baby that is two days old.

**Reasoning**

> Reading this quite literally:
>  
>  "I'm sorry", you say, "but that is impossible. I can complete four, but there is one I cannot do."
>  
>  So clearly, #4 can be completed (Glass containing something other than water)... but #1 cannot! (Which in the order you wrote them, is the one about the baby). 
>  
>  
>  "Keep in mind that this puzzle was spoken, not written down."
>  
>  The mention of speech further suggests that the speaker may have meant to say "I can complete [number] four, but there is [number] one I cannot do." Often words are omitted in speech.

Comment: Interesting idea.

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot, but the task I can't do is:

> Hold in front of me a baby that is exactly two days old.

Because:

> The age will not be exact, it will increase minute by minute.

Comment: i beg to differ - you can hold the baby for a couple of minutes as it's turning exactly 2 days old...

Comment: Nope.  While you are correct about the issue for that task, there is a workaround. As Ben stated.

Comment: Oh,i thought the age will increase constantly, like 2 days and min, 2 days and 2 min..... and as title suggest "infinite precision"

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> stone, because a stone (unit of weight) weights 14 pounds, not one.

because:

> you can hold a baby that is less than 2 days old, and wait awhile. There are international kilogram standards that are made from metal. The metal defines the kilogram. Bring a glass of ice, and wait for it to melt. It is trivial to literally write "all the digits of pi" on a piece of paper. That only leaves the stone as being impossible.

Comment: Nothing the man said requires you to interpret "stone object" in this way.  Also, ice is water.

Comment: According to http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-materials-d_1652.html, phosphate fertilizer has a density of 961 kg/m3. Limestone dust has a density of 1089. Mix them in a 2:1 ratio and it's a density of a little over 1000. This is the same density as some water somewhere at some temperature. "Spring water" is water. The stuff that comes out of your tap is water. The stuff that flows in rivers is water. Seawater, arguably, is water. None of it has a density of exactly 1,000 kg/m3.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> The second one. Kilogram is a unit of mass. You weigh a kg-wt.
>  The first can be done by waiting, as most others have suggested. 
>  The third, I have yet to find a conclusive answer. Suggests? Or we go with @Jon's answer, "It's perfectly possible".
>  Fourth. Gases are fluid, with no specific volume. Take an empty glass, and compress the air, until it matches the density of water. Assume that the glass can withstand it.
>  Fifth. As the others have suggested, either "0123456789", or literally, "All the digits of pi". Or... @Jon's awesome answer. 0,1, as answer is base dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I can do all but four, for I have nothing to write with. If I write with the baby, it will no longer be exactly 2 years old. With either the metal or stone it will become smaller as I use it. To use the glass or the liquid within would again diminish the glass and it shall leak or the liquid will evaporate.